# Динамические формы на django

Tags: python, django

Я создаю web-приложение для своего клуба по рукопашному бою и впервые занимаюсь разработкой в Django.

У меня есть модели, которые я мигрировал в бд. База данных содержит информацию по каждому участнику клуба.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adult = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Вот форма для создание нового участника.
forms.py

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label="Укажите имя ")
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label="Укажите фамилию ")
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    createForm = CreateForm()
    if '_okcreatet' in request.POST:
        firstname = request.POST.get("firstname ")
        lastname = request.POST.get("lastname ")
        adult = request.POST.get("adult ")
        b = Post(firstname='%s' % firstname, lastname='%s' % lastname)  # Внос данных в бд
        b.save()
    if '_okupdate' in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tariff/')
    else:
        return render(request, "index.html", {"form": createForm)
```

index.html

```
<body>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table>
    {{form}}
</table>
<td><input name="_okcreatet" type="submit" value="OK"></td>
<td><input name="_okupdate" onclick="location.href='{% url 'update' %}'" type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

</form>
```

На форме есть две кнопки. "Занести данные нового члена клуба" и "Редактировать список участников". До нажатия на первую кнопку на форме создаётся статическая форма для вноса данных о новом члене.
При нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать список участников" я хочу чтобы  **создавались динамические формы для каждой записи в бд (Форма с изменением фамилии, имени и checkbox для указании участника о его совершеннолетии)**  (для каждого участника клуба), через которые можно осуществлять изменения данных о участнике.

update.html

```
    {% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <!--{{form}}--> <!--На этом месте должны создаваться формы-->
</table>
<td><input name="_okclick" type="submit" value="OK"></td>

</form>
  {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index),
url(r'^update/$', views.updt, name='update'),
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Я очень надеюсь что я ясно объяснил свою проблему ибо первый раз обращаюсь с проблемами на форум. Буду благодарен тем, кто поможет.

Comment: Можно передать queryset с информацией о членах клуба из view в template через context. А затем циклом в template пройтись по queryset и создать формы, проставляя текущие значения. Сделать этот блок с формами скрытым по умолчанию через css, а кнопкой  "Редактировать список участников" открывать его.

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужен formset (formset_factory)

Comment: Возможно тут пригодится ModelForm класс. Он способен генерировать форму по моделям

Answer (score 1):

Если вариант стандартной админки не подходит,
то можно использовать [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) + formset_factory

views.py

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

def formsset_edit(request):
    post_formset = modelformset_factory(Post, fields=('firstname', 'lastname', 'adult'))

    return render(request, "post_formset.html", {'post_formset ': post_formset,})
```